# WordPress custom API endpoint - how to make the request more flexible

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, api

I'm creating simple API endpoint to fetch custom post type items with specified category and tags.

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
  $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'faq',
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array($data['cat']) 
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array($data['tag']) 
                ),
            )
        )
  );
 
  if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
    return null;
    }

        
        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            $id = $post->ID; 

            $posts_data[] = (object) array( 
                    'id' => $id, 
                    'title' => $post->post_title,
                    'content' => $post->post_content
            );
        }                  
    
    return $posts_data;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'test/v1', '/faq/cat=(?P<cat>[a-zA-Z0-9_,]+)/tag=(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z0-9_,]+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );
```

It works fine with this request:
`...wp-json/test/v1/faq/cat=cars/tag=big`
but I would like to make it more flexible, by adding only category, or only tags
`...wp-json/test/v1/faq/cat=cars`
and by adding multiple tags (i.e separated by comma):
`...wp-json/test/v1/faq/cat=cars/tag=big,blue`

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register separate routes for each scenario you want to cover (ie, cat & tag, just cat, or just tag), all done in the single add_action call. The regex you have will support the comma separated tags.

The next thing to do is change how you set the `'term'` parameter as part of the `'tax_query'` array parameter. It's expecting an array of strings, currently you are passing a single string of comma separated values (ie, `'tag1,tag2'`). You can pass the result of using `explode()` to convert the string to an array.

You will also need to implement some conditional logic around setting the `'tax_query'` array parameter based on what route is used.